How do I make the animation of my SVG scene repeatedly?
I created a SVG scenery with an animation when I pressed the sun. However the animation only work once, and then it won't work after that.
Here's my existing JS code.
const sun = document.getElementById("sun");
const stage = document.getElementById("stage");

sun.addEventListener("click", function() {
  sun.style.animationPlayState = "running";
  stage.style.animationPlayState = "running";
});

sun.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  // Reset sun position to its initial values
  sun.setAttribute("cx", "700");
  sun.setAttribute("cy", "100");
  // Set animation state to paused for both sun and stage

  sun.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
  stage.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
});


Welcome to Stack Overflow! For debugging questions please edit your question to include the shortest HTML and CSS necessary to reproduce it. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

There is an article about this which you can read here Restart CSS Animations. From what I understood, the problem is that CSS doesn't have the capability to restart an animation after it has played.
Apart from the solutions given in the article, I found that this works in resetting the animation such that when you click the sun again, it will re-do the animation.


const sun = document.getElementById("sun");
const stage = document.getElementById("stage");

sun.addEventListener("click", function() {
  sun.classList.add("animation");

  sun.style.animationPlayState = "running";
  stage.style.animationPlayState = "running";
});

sun.addEventListener("animationend", function() {
  // Reset sun position to its initial values
  sun.setAttribute("cx", "700");
  sun.setAttribute("cy", "100");
  // Set animation state to paused for both sun and stage
  sun.classList.remove("animation");
});
@keyframes move-left {
  0% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
}

.animation {
  animation: move-left 1s ease-in backwards;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

#sun {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  background: red;
}
<div id="sun">.</div>
<div id="stage"></div>



By adding a class onclick and then removing the class on animationend, the animation will work no matter how many times you "restart" it by clicking on the element.
